# Prepare data on treeview on list

Tags: c#, json, list

I am creating web API and I want to that web api return data on treeview.
Example Input data. (Here just example)

```
0 Movies

1 Comedy

1 SF

2 5th Element

3 Bruce Willis

3 Mila Jovovic

2 Matrix

0 Music

1 Alternative

1 R&R

2 Coldplay

1 Clasic

0 Pictures

1 Trips

2 Europe

3 Stuttgart

4 Mercedes-Benz museum

2 Africa
```

I want to Json output data on treeview

```
{
    'Movies': [
        {'dec':'Comedy '},
        {'dec':'SF', '5th Element'[{'dec':'Bruce Willis','dec':'Mila Jovovic'}],'Matrix'[]},
    ]
}
```

Please give me any example or logic for How to prepare data on list? (Here level is not fixed)

Comment: what is `dec` in your sample JSON which you have provided at the bottom of your code snippet? I can see `Comedy` and `SF` are child of `Movies` node in the tree view.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a place where people write code for you.

Comment: dec is description variable. Please give me example link if you are know. It is prepare data on list on tree format.